# Kill reappearing processes

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, kill-process

I'm making a shell script to kill applications; however I can't kill applications like Xcode that have multiple processes because when I kill the processes already running, new ones appear to take their place, maybe there's a parent process that call the other ones or something, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

`ps -o ppid -p <childpid>` will report the PPID column (parent PID)

Pipe the result to `tail -1` to capture the result:

`$ ps -o ppid 12345 | tail -1`

Comment: The problem with my particular case is that one of the parents is the launchd process, killing all other processes produce a re-apparition of some of them

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the whole process group:

```
 kill -9 -<pid>
```

Note "-" before pid

Comment: it indeed kills the process but it reappear with a new PID